# whats the meaning of 'asInstanceOf[Class[_]]'

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I see this in the code of Spark,I know what is asInstanceOf,but what's the meaning of Class[_]?

```
val newInputFormat = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(inputFormatClass.asInstanceOf[Class[_]], conf)
```

And why use para `inputFormatClass.asInstanceOf[Class[_]]` instead of using `inputFormatClass` directly?

Comment: `Class[_]` is just another class: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html Is like `List[_]` it just means that we don't know / care about the generic type, we only want to cast to the class.

Comment: What's the type of `inputFormatClass` in the 1st place?

Comment: This is the declaration of **inputFormatClass**:` inputFormatClass: Class[_ <: InputFormat[K, V]]`. It is declared in the parameter list of the main constructor of the class **HadoopRDD**.